# How do I make python ask to be the default program for opening media files

Tags: python, windows

I'm building a media player to handle ogg files using python. the media player is done, but now I would like it to be able to ask if the user would like it as their default player for audio files.

I'm not too worried about the actual asking, but how do I make python set that up?

In essence, how do I make python say to windows, every time the user opens bob.ogg, launch mediaplayer.exe?

thanks a lot